# Circles, where do you meet?

Tags: code-golf

Given 2 random circle sections, return how many times they intersect. Rules/clarifications are as below.

1. You are provided 10 total values,

   - The center (x,y) of the circle section
   - Angles of the circle (i.e. (0,90) would be a quarter circle "facing" the top-right corner.
   - The radius of the circle section
2. The circle sections are "drawn" on a 128 by 128 screen, with (0,0) being the center. They have a max radius of 64.
3. You don't need to draw the circles - the program should *only* print out the number of intersections.
4. You can choose to generate the values randomly, in-program, or have the user write it in at program start. (The latter is preferred, but not necessary.)

Below is an example case. As you can see, it has one intersect.

[image: example]

The output should look something like this:

```
$ run ./circle
input (circle 1 center)
input (circle 1 radius)
input (circle 1 angles)
input (more inputs...)
... 
intersections
```

Heres the output for the example case (the prompts are optional):

```
$ run ./circle
c1center: (20,20)
c1radius: 40
c1angles: (210,150)
c2center: (-30,-30)
c2radius: 90
c2angles: (270,180
1
```

Anyway, best of luck! This is code golf, so the minimum number of bytes in any programming language wins!

Oh, and it'd be nice if you could provide a description/link to your program in the answer. Standard Loopholes are not allowed. If you find any errors in my explanation or want me to clarify, just ask. Thanks!

Comment: May we assume that the circles are distinct so that there are not infinite intersections?

Comment: @notjagan yes, circles are completely different in that respect.

Comment: What if the intersection is outside the monitor/screen?

Comment: @user202729 It should be counted - only the center of the circles themselves need to be on-screen. I hope this helps.

Comment: Will the angle be in degrees or radians?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard either is fine, just be sure to specify in your answer.

Comment: Note that challenges should be completely clear since it was posted, because edits to the question may validate existing answers. That's a common mistake with challenges of new users. To achieve that, using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) is often helpful.

Comment: Thanks, @user201729 I'm new to this community, and I'm still trying to work it out. I'll keep it in mind for later questions as well.  Is there a way to move this question to the sandbox?

Comment: @i.. Good first question, you can use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to see how your challenge holds up before posting it next time, but still, good job and I hope to see more of your questions in the future

Comment: @LiefdeWen I'm working on my second question, and it's in the Sandbox now: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/14385#14385

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [numpy](http://numpy.org), <s>310</s> 291 bytes

<sup>-19 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!</sup>

```python
v=lambda c,x,y:sin(arctan2(*c[::-1])-x)>sin(y-x)
def f(a,r,w,x,b,s,y,z):
 d=linalg.norm(b-a)
 if abs(r-s)<d<r+s:e=(r*r-s*s+d*d)/2/d;g=a+e*(b-a)/d;t=(sqrt(r*r-e*e)*(b-a)/d*[1,-1])[::-1];return int(v(g+t-a,w,x)and v(g+t-b,y,z))+int(v(g-t-a,w,x)and v(g-t-b,y,z))-(t==0).all()
from numpy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/BcoMwDETvfIWOlrGTQG4k7o8wOYgYKDNgiOykoT9PIYF2piftzj5pVsMYPnt3nKaHaakrLMFVPdWY@cYJ4msglwp5zbNMJxfUT/xYgnEWkS0rqAQpVl/zRqG8GtU3ZhFY0zaO2nrneu5EoQkjaCqgwgvWHs/2zLHPSiNYzl762EqL@3RvT7WhuJSvldkFI/yNwwsrZYlbIPNELW3epU5chjs7aFwQD1HHQdNSCMlZePviVQzjldD/CP1LaBGMOeCO2lZgVHHfgbt3wwhNN/Qc5DTwcmN@mplGkR8UHC6oIFGghwb2kCrY5ookf8iWHEGuGnH6AQ)

This is a horrible answer.

Takes angles in radians.

Comment: Pretty good answer. I was wondering if anyone could do it in less than 500 bytes. +1

Comment: [291 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY/BcoMwDETvfIWOlrGTQG4k7o8wOYgYKDNgiOykoT9PIYF2piftzj5pVsMYPnt3nKaHaakrLMFVPdWY@cYJ4msglwp5zbNMJxfUT/xYgnEWkS0rqAQpVl/zRqG8GtU3ZhFY0zaO2nrneu5EoQkjaCqgwgvWHs/2zLHPSiNYzl762EqL@3RvT7WhuJSvldkFI/yNwwsrZYlbIPNELW3epU5chjs7aFwQD1HHQdNSCMlZePviVQzjldD/CP1LaBGMOeCO2lZgVHHfgbt3wwhNN/Qc5DTwcmN@mplGkR8UHC6oIFGghwb2kCrY5ookf8iWHEGuGnH6AQ), no need to convert bool to int, `a%(2*pi)<b%(2*pi)` is equivalent to `sin(a)>sin(b)` ...